# Deleting spotify folder at startup

Tags: bash, spotify

I have installed spotify on my ubuntu 12.04 machine. When I start Spotify it simply closes. I found a way to circumvent this problem in some forum: simply remove the folder ~/.cache/spotify
It is however rather annoying that I have to delete this folder every time I want to use Spotify.

My question is, is there a way to tell Ubuntu that it should delete this folder and its content when I start my computer? And if so, how do I do that?

My idea is to add something like the following to the .bashrc file

```
if [ -d ~/.cache/spotify ]; then 
  rmdir ~/.cache/spotify 
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to execute one task at the linux startup I suggest to use /etc/rc.local file.
However, given this is only a workaround you can modify the startup-script of spotfiy adding the **rm -rf /home/your_username/.cache/spotify** before the actual execurion of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a simple alias:

```
alias spotify="rm -rf ~/.cache/spotify && spotify"
```

Add this to your `.bashrc` file and every time you run `spotify`, the cache directory is first deleted (or ignored if it doesn't exist).

Comment: This is a correct and elegant solution but it works only if you execute spotify from the console.

Comment: @matteomattei: if I want to make it work even if I do not execute it from the console, what would I do then?

Comment: @Sune: if you want to make it work also ouside the console, you should modify the original startup script of spotify and add the deletion of the cache folder before the actual execution of the program.

Answer (score 0):

what version of Spotify are you using?  What happens if you set the maximum size for cache in the Preferences to 0?